# how to convert pandas columns to rows dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
code   tank  noz_sale_cumsum  noz_1_sub  noz_2_sub   noz_1_avg   noz_2_avg  noz_1_flag  noz_2_flag 
123    1     1234             12         23          23.23       32.45      short       ok                
123    2     1200             13         53          33.13       22.45      excess      ok
```

columns such as `noz_1_sub, noz_2_sub, noz_1_avg, noz_2_avg, noz_1_flag and noz_2_flag` are generated dynamically. 
My desired dataframe would be following.

```
code  tank  noz_no   noz_sale_cumsum  noz_sub   noz_avg   noz_flag
123   1     1        1234             12        23.23     short
123   1     2        1234             23        32.45     ok
123   2     1        1200             13        33.13     excess
123   2     2        1200             53        22.45     ok
```

I am doing following in pandas.

```
first I am getting all dynamic columns in different arrays

cols_sub = [cols for cols in df.columns if re.search('noz_\d+_sub', cols)]
cols_avg = [cols for cols in df.columns if re.search('noz_\d+_avg', cols)]
cols_flag = [cols for cols in df.columns if re.search('noz_\d+_flag', cols)]

final_df = df.pivot_table(index=['code', 'tank', 'noz_sale_cumsum'], columns=[cols_sub, cols_avg, cols_flag], values=[]).reset_index()
```

I am not sure about values column and how do I extract number from `noz` like columns and put it under `noz_no` column. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `melt` to convert everything to rows then use `pivot_table` to convert back some rows to columns.

```
a = df.melt(id_vars=['code', 'tank', 'noz_sale_cumsum'])
a['noz_no'] = a.variable.map(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
a['kpi'] = a.variable.map(lambda x: 'noz_' + x.split('_')[2])
```

[image]

```
a.pivot_table(
    values='value',
    index=['code', 'tank', 'noz_sale_cumsum', 'noz_no'],
    columns=['kpi'], aggfunc='first'
).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting `IndexError: list index out of range` for this line `a['kpi'] = a.variable.map(lambda x: 'noz_' + x.split('_')[2])
`

Comment: Does your dataframe have more columns than those in your example ? You may want to add these columns to `id_vars` in `melt` call

Comment: Yes, I have more columns. I have added it to `id_vars` in `melt`. I have 5 columns in it so given `a['kpi'] = a.variable.map(lambda x: 'noz_' + x.split('_')[4])` but still getting the same error.

Comment: Why `[4]` ?  The `map` is to transform `noz_1_sub` to `noz_1`. What does `a.variable.value_counts()` give ?

Comment: `a.variable.value_counts()` is 2. I have column name as `nozzle_1_avg` and not `noz_1_avg` will that make a difference?

Comment: I did something like this `a['kpi'] = a.variable.map(lambda x: 'nozzle_' + x.split('_')[1])` ,but my `kpi` column values are `nozzle_1,nozzle_2..etc`